# Inconsistent rounding with ToExpression

Tags: conversion

I am trying to convert a string which contains a decimal number into a number with out any lost of precision. For example the string `5000000.0000000009` should become the number `5000000.0000000009` and not `5000000.000000001` Using the built in function like `ToExpression` certain numbers are rounded to machine precision but not all.

For example:

```
FullForm@ToExpression @ "5000000.0000000009"
```

Outputs:

```
5.000000000000001`*^6
```

Note: ToExpression returns the correct result for other slightly different numbers.

```
FullForm@ToExpression @ "5000000.00000000099"
```

Outputs:

```
5.00000000000000099`17.69897000433602*^6
```

Why does ToExpression round some numbers and not others or am I misunderstanding the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression) converts number strings to machine precision if it can. Your example is an edge case where [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression) converts the number to machine precision, but the machine real is not able to store all of the digits. One workaround is to indicate the precision explicitly:

```
ToExpression["5000000.0000000009`17"]//InputForm
```

> 5.0000000000000009`17.*^6

Note that converting the above extended precision number into a machine number yields the result that you were getting before:

```
N @ ToExpression["5000000.0000000009`17"] //InputForm
```

> 5.000000000000001*^6

Your other examples where things work as expected are because [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression) is forced to convert to an extended precision number, or [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression) converts to a machine number that is capable of representing all of the digits.

Comment: This it would seem would require the user then to edit all the input strings (may be they are in files) and add the correct `nn values to each string? Is this correct?

Comment: My actual solution is to split the decimals on the periods and then use FromDigits to build a fraction, but I was interested in why it happens.